# Build web api .net core on linux

Tags: asp.net, .net, linux, azure-devops, ubuntu-16.04

I'm using continuous integration with Microsoft (R) Visual Studio (R) Team Services . After the `dotnet restore` command which successfully runs on my ubnuntu server, then I run the build command `dot net build` and the next error occurs:

`(GetReferenceAssemblyPaths target) -> 
         /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/1.0.0-preview3-004056/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1107,5): error MSB3644: The reference assemblies for framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" were not found. To resolve this, install the SDK or Targeting Pack for this framework version or retarget your application to a version of the framework for which you have the SDK or Targeting Pack installed. Note that assemblies will be resolved from the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) and will be used in place of reference assemblies. Therefore your assembly may not be correctly targeted for the framework you intend.`

What did I wrong? I tried to modify the .net version to 4.0, I also looked into some commands to get the targeting pack for linux but I can't find a solution.

My system runs:

- Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
- .net core 1.0.0 preview 3

Comment: You could use tool like flubu to make things easier around build process. Mora about flubu on: stackoverflow.com/questions/40890522/… Btw se examples for .net core. Answer is for .net

Answer (score 1):

Based on the error, your project references to .net framework 4.5, you need to reference to .net core.

1. Open project.json
2. Check the section of frameworks, the code should be like this (modify it if the value is “net452”{}):

Code:

```
"frameworks": {
    //"net452": { }
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },
```